Elastic python request timeout error: Pool reached maximum size and no more connections are allowed
I am using Elasticsearch python module. I am trying to set up a connection to the sever like this
es = Elasticsearch([config.endpoint],
                    api_key=config.key,
                    request_timeout=config.request_timeout )

The server connects, then I try to execute enrichment policies.
es.enrich.execute_policy(name=policy)

But they all fail with this error:
{'policy': 'enrich-1', 'status': 'failed', 'error': "Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: FullPoolError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='our.server.internal', port=9200): Pool reached maximum size and no more connections are allowed.))"}

If I remove the request_timeout parameter, the enrichment trys to run but says timeout. If I put the parameter back then I get this error.
Why is this happening? I tried reading the documentation but its not clear what any of these parameters actually do. Is there somewhere that details what exactly each of these parameters do? I tried using connections_per_node=50 didn't help, same error.
What am I doing wrong?
